# How to adjust the base url for xampp to the folder that contains the code

Tags: xampp

This is probably a stupid stupid question but I'm hoping that there's a trick I can do with .htaccess or something.

In my XAMPP structure, I have my project sitting in a folder under htdocs:

```
|- /htdocs
|-- /dist
|--- index.html
|--- *.js
```

In index.html I have:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MyApp</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

When I go to `http://localhost/dist` I get some errors because it can't find the js files it's looking for under `/localhost/*.js` is there a way I can have a dynamic redirection in `.htaccess` or another place that would make point the base url to `/dist` instead of `/localhost`?

The only way I can think of is playing with the host file and having a local domain (i.e. `mylocaldomain.com` -> `localhost/dist`) but I want something more dynamic so I wouldn't have to set it up for every folder under localhost.

Doable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MyApp</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/inline.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Keep all *.js files in a folder named js